# get database views

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

```
CREATE VIEW customer_ro (name, language, credit)
      AS SELECT cust_last_name, nls_language, credit_limit
      FROM customers
```

How do i get the names of the aliases(i.e name, language, and credit) with respect to a particular view from the database.(oracle)....

i need to use it via jdbc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although views no longer appear in `USER_TABLES`, they are still in `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` (and `DBA_` and `ALL_` equivalents). So you can do this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CUSTOMER_RO'
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;
```

From jdbc you'd parameterise that, but otherwise the same query will work.

Comment: well this is giving me the list of columns in the table 'customers'..
What i need is the list that will contain (name, language,credit)....

Comment: It gives me the *view* column names when I use the view name in the query. I've just re-tested this and it works. (10.2.0.5 and 9.2.0.8 on Solaris). Not sure what you could be doing differently.